# getting error while trying to style elements by ID in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So I have problem in ReactJS. I'm trying to make simple dropdown with JavaScript.(no need to write the CSS examples to make dropdowns. I need it in js because I will have delays on it).

My code for that is:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Header extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.dropdown = React.createRef();
 }

 handleMouseOver = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.dropdown.current.id.style.display = 'block';
 };

 render() {
  return (
   <header id="header">
     <div onMouseOver={e => this.handleMouseOver(e)}>
       <ul>
         <li className="dropdown">Categories</li>
         <ul id="menu" className="sub-menu" ref={this.dropdown}>
           <li>Computerss & Office</li>
         </ul>
       </ul>
     </div>
   </header>
  )
 }
}
export default Header;
```

In CSS I have:

```
.menu {
 display: none;
}
```

and with

```
this.dropdown.current.id.style.display = 'block';
```

I want to make dropdown appear. However, when the mouse moves over `div` I get error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined

Interesting part is that when I try to

```
console.log(this.dropdown.current.id);
alert(this.dropdown.current.id);
```

I get output:

> menu

Totally same was when I was passing variable in js function using only js and doing `document.getElementById(elementId).style.display = "block";` but offcourse I could alert it or `console.log`

But when I insert ID by writing in js function it works perfectly:

```
document.getElementById('menu').style.display = "block";
```

So problem appears while trying to pass `ID`. Any clue why this is happening ?

Comment: you should use className for style in react js

Comment: if this.dropdown.current is the element, .id a string property on the element, then this.dropdown.current.style is the style property associated with the element.

Comment: you try with `this.dropdown.style.display = 'block';` instead of getting menu from id because it return only string data and you can't get style from string data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constructor you need to bind `this` to your event handler

```
constructor() {
    super(props);
    this.dropdown = React.createRef();
    this.handleMouseOver = this.handleMouseOver.bind(this);
}
```

and you can also simplify your event reference to this:

```
<div onMouseOver={this.handleMouseOver}>
```

Also the way you are planning to show/hide the list can be done using the component's state instead of manually changing the CSS value of the HTML element.

You should create a state like this in the constructor:

```
this.state = {
    isHovering: false
}
```

Then in your hover event handler, you can set this `isHovering` value to true.

With this in place, your render method could render the list only when the `isHovering` value is true:

```
<div onMouseOver={e => this.handleMouseOver(e)}>
   <ul>
     <li className="dropdown">Categories</li>
     {this.state.isHovering?(
         <ul id="menu" className="sub-menu">
             <li>Computerss & Office</li>
         </ul>
     ):null}
   </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: maybe you have way how to repeat same code for other dropdown otherwise is not DRY and i need write multiple time same code. Im new in reactjs still dont know all possibilities. Thanks

Comment: Yes you can move your dropdown structure into a new React component and then use it from inside your `Header` component using for example: `<MyDropDown />`